# secure calculation form with php and jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a page that user can enter label size and quantity and get the price (print and cut).

I get data from db:

```
<?php
    require_once('connect.php');
    $sql = "SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts where post_title='label'";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $priceInput = $row['post_content']; }}else{echo "error" ;}
?>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass');
if(!$connection){
    echo "faild to connect to db" . die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
$dbselect = mysqli_select_db($connection,'dbName');
if(!$dbselect){
    echo "faild to select db" . die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

And with jquery calculate the price

This page works fine in calculate the price but i have 2 question:

1. is this form and this way to interact with db safe and secure? or in what ways i can secure it?
2. user can easily change values in inspect and my calculation goes wrong, how can I check it server side and when user submit the form, right values be posted?

```js
var priceInput = JSON.parse('[["page printing price","printPrice","100"],["price of each cut","eachCutPrice","1"],["minimum cutting price","cutMin","100"],["other service","other","20"],["pageSize","25","31"]]');


function calculate() {
  var labelType = $('#labelType').val();
  var labelShape = $('#labelShape').val();
  var diameter = $('#diameter').val();
  var quantity = ($('#quantity').val());

  for (var i = 0; i < priceInput.length; i++) {
    if (priceInput[i][1] == "printPrice") {
      var pagePrice = priceInput[i][2]*1;
    }
    if (priceInput[i][1] == "eachCutPrice") {
      var eachCutPrice = priceInput[i][2]*1;
    }
    if (priceInput[i][1] == "cutMin") {
      var cutMin = priceInput[i][2]*1;
    }
    if (priceInput[i][1] == "other") {
      var other = priceInput[i][2]*1;
    }
    if (priceInput[i][0] == "pageSize") {
      var pWidth = priceInput[i][1]*1;
      var pHeight = priceInput[i][2]*1;
    }
  }
  //claculate page and cut numbers
  var cutNum = Math.floor(pWidth / (diameter)) * Math.floor(pHeight / (diameter));
  var pageNum = Math.ceil(quantity / cutNum);
  var cutPrice = Math.max((cutNum * eachCutPrice), cutMin);
  var cutPriceAll = cutPrice * pageNum;
  var finalPrice = pageNum * (pagePrice + cutPriceAll) + other;
  $("#finalPricePlace").html(" price : " + finalPrice.toLocaleString());
}

calculate();

$("#diameter").on('input', calculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="price" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="diameter">diameter (cm): </label></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="20" value="1.0" step="0.1" name="diameter" id="diameter">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="quantity">quantity: </label></td>
      <td>
        <select name="quantity" id="quantity" onchange="calculate()">
          <option value="100">100 PCs</option>
          <option value="200">200 PCs</option>
          <option value="500">500 PCs</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<div class="priceTab">
  <p class="priceP"><span id="finalPricePlace"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: As long there is no direct access to the SQL statement you should be safe

Comment: First: yes. Two. Dunno.

Comment: For the server side. I would recommend doing a server side calculation

Comment: There's nothing _obviously_ insecure about the code so far. It depends what specific threats you are thinking of. Anyway, to check the calculation on the server, you need to take the submitted input values and perform the calculation again. You arent sending the final price in your form, so you'd need to repeat it on the server in any case, in order to know what to charge the customer.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the JSON or an object to the code for a [mcve]

Comment: i wanted to post finalPrice to cart page but i noticed user can easily manipulate it so i should write all calculations with php too?

Comment: All calculations must be done on the server side where the user could benefit from modifying the results! You can calculate a final price in js for display purposes, but for billing purposes the price must be calculated on the server side.